# python_ hh:mm:ss.000 in excel converts to dataframe by xlwings has problem

Tags: python, dataframe, time, xlwings

When I build exe file because of DRM i can't use `pd.read_excel` or `pd.ExcelFile` for open excel files. So I try to use `xlwings` for open the DRM excel file. But time data converts to something strange data...by xlwings. I don't know what's it and how to fix.

-here is time data-
[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw
import os

app = xw.App(visible=False)
xlsx2 = xw.Book('tt.xlsm')
ref_sheet = xlsx2.sheets[1].used_range.options(pd.DataFrame, index=0, header=1, chunksize=10000).value
xlsx2.close()
app.kill()
```

result :

```
0        0.340030

1        0.340031

2        0.340034

3        0.340038

4        0.340038
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, *Time* is stored as daytime divided by 24 hours. As an experiment, enter `=1/24` into a cell, select *Time* as the number format, and you should see `01:00:00` or something similar (depending on your region).

In other words, the numbers you get are fractions of a day. To interpret them as a time, use `datetime.timedelta`:

```py
ref_sheet = xlsx2.sheets[1].used_range.options(
    pd.DataFrame, index=0, header=1, chunksize=10000,
    numbers=datetime.timedelta
).value
```

As an alternative, we can use `pandas.to_timedelta` to convert already obtained data:

```py
ref_sheet = xlsx2.sheets[1].used_range.options(
    pd.DataFrame, index=0, header=1, chunksize=10000).value
ref_sheet = pd.to_timedelta(ref_sheet, unit='D')
```

where `unit='D'` means *interpret the numbers as the number of days*.

Comment: Thanks a lot 
I used second way. beacuse first way change other data also.
but recover data format is little bit difference before
orginal : 08:09:38.642000
recover data : 0days 08:09:38.642025600
how can I delete '0days' and limit the miliseconds (ex)38 .642025600 -> 38.642

Comment: @jwjjang If the answer was helpful, I suggest [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). As for the second question, it concerns the representation of time. I highly recommend looking for the [answer on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+Format+timedelta+to+string). And if there is no suitable one, formulate your new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).